# DataGridView Goes Behind GroupBox When Adding Values

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, groupbox

1. I create a groupBox
2. I create a dataGridView inside the groupbox
3. I create a button to add values into the dataGridView

Here is the situation...

When I start debugging the program, everything looks fine. But when i click the button to add values to the dataGridView, the dataGridView goes behind the groupBox.

I tried to "Bring to Front" the dataGridView, but that doesn't work either.

What could be the problem?

Comment: How do you create the controls? In the designer? if so, can you move the groupbox and the dgv moves with it? what is the code in the button click?

Comment: I create the controls from the toolbox. Yes, the groupbox moves with the dgv. With the code... I am Invoking a UIUpdaterDelegate to add values to my columns.

Comment: Sounds weird. Can it be anything in the Button_Click code? (Do delete the BringToFront. It won't help here..)